# Boost build system not setting the compiler version tag for the output library names

Tags: c++, layout, boost, build, bjam

This is a silly question but I cannot find anything in the boost documentation, the boost build system is not appending the correct compiler version tag to the libraries it produces.

Here is the command I use to build my boost 1.62.0 libraries:

```
b2 --build-dir=build toolset=msvc-12 address-model=64 threading=single link=shared,static variant=debug,release -j 12 --layout=versioned --stagedir=msvc
```

I expect to end up with libraries looking like this:

```
boost_date_time-vc120-mt-gd-1_62.dll
```

However, I have this:

```
boost_date_time-vc-mt-gd-1_62.dll
```

The build system is not setting the compiler version tag, leaving me only with **vc** instead of **vc120**.

From the documentation, the **--layout=versioned** option is supposed to get me the layout I want:

```
#   --layout=<layout>       Determines whether to choose library names
#                           and header locations such that multiple
#                           versions of Boost or multiple compilers can
#                           be used on the same system.
#
#                               versioned - Names of boost binaries
#                               include the Boost version number, name and
#                               version of the compiler and encoded build
#                               properties.  Boost headers are installed in a
#                               subdirectory of <HDRDIR> whose name contains
#                               the Boost version number.
```

Is there something I am missing? Why is the tag not set correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of pulling my hair out, I found the issue:

```
toolset=msvc-12
```

should in fact be:

```
toolset=msvc-12.0
```

Yes. That's it.

The build system was happily building the libraries with msvc12 but was not able to add the compiler version without this '**.0**'.

Comment: should be an accepted answer! :) was wondering the same as "msvc-v110" value was working for for a build, but no suffix as well.